# Why this script crashes Blender when resizing an image empty?

Tags: python, scripting

If I run the next script, it works ok, but when I create an image empty, and try to resize or move it grabbing its gizmo, Blender (2.93) crashes. Does anybody know, why? The script is not too useful in this form, because it is just the critical line of a larger script, I removed the irrelevant parts.

````
import bpy

from bpy.app.handlers import persistent

@persistent
def my_handler(scene):
    bpy.context.preferences.themes[0].view_3d.space.gradients.high_gradient = (.1,.2,.3)

bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.append(my_handler)
```
````

Comment: IMO don't mix context with handlers. Use the `scene` and `depsgraph` arguments passed, if available.

Comment: handlers exist outside of the general context, and especially since you're using a `@persistent` decorator, it might get called in a wrong context or non existent context. Undo/redo and save/load will most likely cause a crash here. Maybe you want to explore timers instead of handlers : https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.timers.html